# Multi-Buy Promotion With Multiple Products

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working with SAP Commerce v1811 and I need to create a Multi-Buy Promotion which applies to multiple products? The case is for example for variants, lest say we have:

```
Product A1 - $10 
Product A2 - $10
Product A3 - $10
```

And a Promo "Buy 4 Products A of any kind by $35"

So If I take any combination (for example: 3A1-1A2, 4A3, 2A1-2A3) it will be $35 and the other units at normal price,for example:

```
3A1 + 1A2 + 1A3 = 45
3A1 + 1A2 + 2A3 = 55
8A1 = 70
```

For the case where is only one product (for example 8A1) I could do it with a target bundle price action

Version: v1811

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use the BaseProduct and Variants concept it should be sufficient to include the base product in the condition (as base products and their variants are properly supported since 6.7).

So e.g. you have a base product A with variants A1 - A10.
To select the products you need a qualifying products condition.
If you want all variants to trigger the promotion you can just include only the base product.
If you want only a subset of the variants to trigger the promotion, you need to have the qualifying products condition with only those variants and the CONTAINS_ANY selector.

To get the "Buy 4" part to work you need to use containers.
So you have a container "X" in the conditions and add the qualifying products condition inside of that container.
(Make sure to set the quantity in the qualifying products container to 1, not your target quantity 4!)

As an action use the target bundle price action (with mapping of container "X" and quantity 4)

To restrict how often this promotion can be applied (e.g. buy 4, get it applied once, buy 8 get it twice etc) you have to set the "maximum rule executions" value in the source rule higher. So e.g. to limit customers from having this applied more than twice, you would set that value to 2. Then even if they have 12 in the cart, the promotion only triggers twice.

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Sebastian